# UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath scrolls to the wrong path

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have two UICollectionViews and when the user scrolls on one, the other should also change by scrolling to the same index path. I've implemented the following code so that, when the first `UICollectionView` decelerates and lands on one cell, the second `UICollectionView` should automatically scroll to that same `IndexPath`:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Only do this for the first UICollectionView
    if (scrollView.tag == 0) {
        // Find the new IndexPath
        CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.filterCollectionView.contentOffset, .size = self.filterCollectionView.bounds.size};
        CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
        NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath = [self.filterCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:visiblePoint];

        // On main thread, scroll second CollectionView to visibleIndexPath
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Row: %li, Sec: %li", visibleIndexPath.row, visibleIndexPath.section);
            [self.filterTitleCollectionView reloadData];
            [self.filterTitleCollectionView layoutIfNeeded];
            [self.filterTitleCollectionView setNeedsDisplay];
            //scroll titles to same index path
            [self.filterTitleCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:visibleIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
            
            NSLog(@"Row: %li, Sec: %li", self.filterTitleCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems[0].row, self.filterTitleCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems[0].section);
            
        });
    }
}
```

For some reason, the filterTitleCollectionView does not scroll to the visibleIndexPath. Or if it does scroll, it scrolls to the wrong cell (in a predictable pattern). You can see the video of it here:

https://streamable.com/q2lnnw

The row number is in the title of the cell. As you can see, the second `UICollectionView` keeps scrolling to row `2` for some reason.

The correct `IndexPath` is printed, but it scrolls to the wrong `IndexPath` or doesn't scroll at all.

Comment: when scrolling the 2nd view, why do you call `reloadData`, `layoutIfNeeded`, and `setNeedsDisplay`? try not doing that.

Comment: I input those on recommendations from other SO threads. If I remove them, the behavior does not change. @mr.fixit